# Generating prototype methods

Tags: coffeescript

I am attempting to generate methods on a coffeescript class, like so:

```
class Test
  log: (msg...) ->
    for m in msg
      console.log(m)

  for alias in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
     Test::[alias] = (v...) ->
      o = {}
      o[alias] = v[0]
      Test::log.apply(@, [o].concat(v.slice(1)))

t = new Test()
t.one(1)
t.two(3)
```

For reasons that fully escape me, this prints out

```
{ five: 1 }
{ five: 2 }
```

rather than what I had expected, being:

```
{ one: 1 }
{ two: 2 }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding `alias` variable to the new value on each iteration of the `for` loop. So, when `t.one(1)` method is called `alias` variable is bound to `'five'`.

There are two ways of fixing this problem.

First solution is to use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'].forEach (alias) ->
  Test::[alias] = (v...) ->
    // ..
```

Second solution is to use coffee-script `do` statement to create a closure:

```
for alias in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
  Test::[alias] = do (alias) -> (v...) ->
    // ..
```